# URL Rewrite with a twist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having trouble with my rewriting of a certain URL.

I am doing some site moving and Google still has some old URLs in its index that it crawls that I would like to redirect to the new page. I was thinking before I do a query string strip on the query strings and redirect, I was wondering if you can accomplish this in mod_rewrite first? I currently have this in my .htaccess but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^news.php?action=view&title=(.*) /blog.php?article_keyword=$1 [L]
```

The environment is Linux with Apache

Comment: You cannot do it this way -- `RewriteRule` does not work with query string directly -- only with help of `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=view&title=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news\.php/?$ /blog.php?article_keyword=%1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it this way -- `RewriteRule` does not work with query string directly -- only with help of `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=view&title=(.*)
RewriteRule ^news.php$ /blog.php?article_keyword=%1 [R=301,L]
```

I've added `R=301` flag to issue permanent redirect, so Google will know that old URL is no longer in use and it should use new URL instead. If you do not need such redirect, then rmove it and only leave `L` flag.